# Difference between sequential and combined predicates

Tags: selenium, xpath

In Selenium I have written a `xpath` and both of them retrieves the same result.

```
//a[@role='tab'][text()=' Assets']
//a[@role='tab' and text()=' Assets']
```

Does both of them have the same meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases `a[b][c]` has exactly the same effect as `a[b and c]`. There are two exceptions to be aware of:

- They are not equivalent if either predicate is numeric, or has a dependency on `position()` or `last()` (I call these *positional predicates*). For example `a[@x][1]` selects the first `a` element that has an `@x` attribute, while `a[1][@x]` selects the first `a` element provided it has an `@x` attribute (and selects nothing otherwise). By contrast `a[1 and @x]` converts the integer 1 to the boolean `true()`, so it just means `a[@x]`.
- There may be differences in behaviour if evaluation of `b` or `c` fails with a dynamic error. The precise rules here depend on which version of XPath you are using, and to be honest the rules leave implementations some leeway, but you need to exercise care if you want to be sure that in the event of `b` being false, `c` is not evaluated. (This hardly matters in XPath 1.0 because very few expressions throw dynamic errors.)

Comment: Thank you for answering, so simplifying: don't use number with `and` because it'll be ignored

Comment: @user7294900 , if you want to use node index along with other predicates, use it as `[position()=1 and @x]`, but not `[1 and @x]`

Comment: @use7294900 No it won't be ignored, it will be turned into a boolean. 0=false, everything else = true.

Answer (score 1):

When you add Square Brackets ([]) to XPath you are adding a condition, so

first row adding 2 conditions

Which produce similar results as adding condition with `and`

Normally you don't use first row, because it less readable,

Mainly because this syntax represent in other languages a [Matrix](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/22library/Matrix.java.html)

> ```
> // return a random m-by-n matrix with values between 0 and 1
> public static double[][] random(int m, int n) {
> ```

See [tutorial](http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/XPath_tutorial_-_basics):

> 5 **XPaths with predicates**
>
> A predicate is an expression that can be true or false
>
> It is appended within [...] to a given location path and will refine results
>
> More than one predicate can be appended to and within (!) a location path

Comment: If you read XPath thinking that symbols have the same meaning as in other languages you have encountered in the past, then you're making life very difficult for yourself.

Comment: @MichaelKay it doesn't say it won't happen, specially if using xpath in java code

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a predicate, which means it checks if `a[@role='tab']` is true then it proceeds to `[text()=' Assets']`

The second one is a just using an `and` operator so it validates both are true.